# Checking if JSON object exists

Tags: python, json

**Introduction:**

I'm currently working with JSON and Python, building a web-scraper and anayisig the data. However sometimes the data that I want to scrape does not always get returned due to the IP getting blocked or rerouted or any of the other troubles one can encounter when scraping. So I want to check if the object in the JSON file exists before further processing.

**Goal:**

To catch if the object was/wasn't grabbed by the scraper using an if statement and searching the JSON file.

**What I Have Tried:**

- Using `if data["caption"] in data:`,
- Using a for loop for the data,
- Calling the object directly as `if data["caption"]:` and `if "caption":`,
- For the loop; `for s in range(len(data)):` and `if data[s]["caption"]:`

**Errors:**

- `KeyError: 'caption'`
- `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

**Code:**

```
[{
  "caption": "This is water.",
  "images": [],
  "timestamp": "2022-02-08T03:44:20.000Z",
},
{
  "caption": "old man and the sea",
  "images": [],
  "timestamp": "2022-01-12T17:58:24.000Z",
},
{
  "caption": "from last night",
  "images": [],
  "timestamp": "2021-12-02T15:52:26.000Z",
}]
```

```
import json

with open('result.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    for s in range(len(data)):
        if data[s]["caption"]:
          print("Caption is here")
        else:
          print("Caption is not here")
```

Currently the code will only work if the object 'caption' is in the code, however shows `KeyError: 'caption'` when it hits a part of the file which does not have 'caption' in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try using `data[s].get("caption")` instead of `data[s]["caption"]`.

Comment: Try using ```data[s].get('caption', None)``` in the ``if`` condition.
or You can use try except block and catch the KeyError exception.

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate, but just in case it's not clear how it applies, you want `if "caption" in data[s]:`. If anything's still unclear, LMK.

Comment: @Muhammad `.get(..., None)` is redundant. You can just use `.get(...)`.

Comment: @wjandrea I Agree, it's for better readability to indicate the default value of the key is not found.

Comment: BTW, what you're calling an "object" is actually called a *property* in JS terminology, or a *key* in Python terminology.

Comment: Also BTW, JSON is irrelevant to the problem since you're loading it just fine; the problem occurs *after* loading it; or in other words, if you put that data directly in your Python script, you'd have the same problem.

Comment: @wjandrea Oh man, you guys have just made up for hours of searching. Thank you!

Comment: Also also BTW, get out of the habit of using `for s in range(len(data)):`. You can just do `for d in data:`, and then `if "caption" in d:`.